# event.target.id.indexOf("foo") not working - Not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, indexof

I have a JavaScript function that loops through classes and gets an ID which I have wrapped in a div called 'item'. Once they click on a button it bubbles up through the div which I have wrapped information in and collected the ID. For Example:

```
output = "<div id='item" + json_output[i].id + "'>" +
  "<div class = 'itemBoxes'>"+
  "<h3 class ='itemTitle'>" +json_output[i].classname + "</h3>" +
  "<div class = 'paddingBottom'></div>" +
  "<p class = 'itemDesc'>" + json_output[i].classdescription + '</p>' +
  "<div class ='itemInfo'>" +
  "<div class ='bookingItems'> <img src = 'img/glyphicons-268-credit-card.png'</img> <p class = 'itemDetails'>Â£" + json_output[i].classprice + "</p></div> "+
  "<div class ='bookingItems'> <img src = 'img/glyphicons-46-calendar.png'</img> <p class = 'itemDetails'>" + json_output[i].classdate + "</p></div>" +
  "<div class ='bookingItems'> <img src = 'img/glyphicons-55-clock.png'</img><p class = 'itemDetails'>"+ json_output[i].classstarttime +"</p></div>" +
  "<div class ='bookingItems'> <img src = 'img/glyphicons-44-group.png'</img><p class = 'itemDetails'>" + json_output[i].classparticipants + " spaces </p></div>" +
  "</div>" +
  "<p id ='bookingBox'> <input type='button' class='bookingSubmit' value='Book Now'/> </p>" +
  "</div>" +
  "</div>";
  target.innerHTML += output;
```

The code I use to find the ID is:

```
var fetchModifyButton;
//Gets the button that says 'Modify'
fetchModifyButton = _c("bookingSubmit");
//Remove Button.
for (var i = 0, j = fetchModifyButton.length; i < j; i++) {
    fetchModifyButton[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
      var e, productID, newID;
        //Bubbles up and finds the ID of the product they want to modify
        e = event.target;
        while (e.id.indexOf('item') == -1) {
            e = e.parentNode;
        }
        productID = e.id;
        //Removes everything but the numbers.
        newID = productID.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        getClassInfoForBooking(newID, newID);
    });
}
```

This works perfectly in Google Chrome, IE11, and most other browsers.

It doesn't work in IE8,9 or 10.

The error message I get in is:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'id' of undefinded or null reference

*Then it points to the line: `while (e.id.indexOf('item') == -1) {`*

I wondered if anyone had any ideas why?

Comment: I didn't take a look at the rationale behind your code but from first glance, you didn't add "event" in between the function parentheses on line 6

Answer (score 0):

use `event.srcElement` for IE

```
var addEvent =  window.addEventListener||window.attachEvent;
fetchModifyButton[i].addEvent("click", function () {
    var e, productID, newID;
    //Bubbles up and finds the ID of the product they want to modify
    e = event.target||event.srcElement;
    while (e.id.indexOf('item') == -1) {
        e = e.parentNode;
    }
    productID = e.id;
    //Removes everything but the numbers.
    newID = productID.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    getClassInfoForBooking(newID, newID);
});
```

Comment: @Teemu IE8 doesn't support `event.target` but has `event.srcElement` instead.

Comment: @Teemu Right, I thought IE7 was the last one without addEventListener.

Comment: I am just about to test it, thanks for the suggestion, should this work from IE7 through to IE10? I'm interested what the event.srcElement does differently to event.target?

Comment: @user3180997 I've no clue, why your code fails in IE9-10 (unless the DTD is incorrect?). This anwser fixes the issue with IE8, whose event handling model differs totally from modern browsers.